# Node Js, AWS Lambda How can I get nested asynchronous methods variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I have written this lambda function in node js 8.10. This is not assign the value properly in the asynchronous1 method

```
                var response; 
                var client = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs();
                var  params = {logGroupName: group};
                client.describeMetricFilters(params, function(err, data) {
                   if(err) { console.log(err);}
                   else{
                   for(let p of data.metricFilters){
                      var  patterns = [/\$\.errorCode\s*=\s*\"?\*UnauthorizedOperation(\"|\)|\s)/i, /\$\.errorCode\s*=\s*\"?AccessDenied\*(\"|\)|\s)/i];
                       if(findinString(patterns, p.filterPattern)){
                           var cwclient = new AWS.CloudWatch();
                           var response;
                           var par = {MetricName: p.metricTransformations[0].metricName, Namespace: p.metricTransformations[0].metricNamespace };
                           cwclient.describeAlarmsForMetric(function(par,data){
                               if(err){console.log(err);}
                               else{ response = data; }
                           });
                           var snsClient = new  AWS.SNS();
                           var subscribers;
                           var yh = { TopicArn:  response.MetricAlarms[0].AlarmActions[0] };
                           snsClient.listSubscriptionsByTopic(yh, function(err, data){
                              if(err){console.log(err);}
                              else {subscribers = data;}  
                           });
                           if(subscribers.Subscriptions.length == 0){
                               result = true;
                           }
```

now in the above mthod first asynchronous method  `describeMetricFilters`  inside it there are 2 asynchronous method `describeAlarmsForMetric` and `listSubscriptionsByTopic` ...But I ca nnot get the `response` value which is set in the  inside of the async method ...

```
cwclient.describeAlarmsForMetric(function(par,data){
                               if(err){console.log(err);}
                               else{ response = data; }
                           });
```

it did not set the value...when I trying to access `response from outside asynchronous method after setting the value I can not see any value stored in it...

Also same thing happen for here

`if(subscribers.Subscriptions.length == 0)` subscribers value can not display always return udefined...

So How can I handle this...Should I make await for these asynchronous methods....I am new on node js so any suggestion would be great for me.....

Basically how the variables which are assigned values inside of an async method would accessible outside of the async method.   Or is there any better way to handle this??